# How Do I Transfer Listbox Items Into A Textbox By Clicking A Button C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a Listbox in which items are collcted.

I want all items in listbox to be transferred into textbox by clicking a button.

And each item must be separated by character #

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 2):

```
 string str1 = "";
            foreach(var k in listBox1.Items)
            {
                str1  = str1 + " #" + k; 
            }
            textBox1.Text = str1;
```